# Ruby on Rails application could not be started (mysql error 2002)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, sockets

I got a OSX Server, i updated it to 10.6.5 from 10.6.4.
Since then my Ruby on Rails Application (leihs) gibes me an Error.
"your config/databse.yml may not be written correctly. Please check it and fix any errors.
Your databse schema may be out of date or nonexistant. ....
The database server may not be running. Please check whether it's running, and start if it isn't

Error message:
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql:error)

Then a looong list of backtraces whitch dont really help me.

The Socket file does NOT exist, and i cant find it on other places.

Please help me, this is making me crazy.

Thanks for your time & help

Comment: which config file? database.yml ?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/92469/my.cnf   here the my.cf file

Comment: The database.yml file. Can you connect to the server via the command line?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/92469/database.yml   ----  Connect via command line? im not sure if i did correct but i tried mysql -u root -p  // then it says enter password, i type in the password -> can't connect ... mysql.sock' (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem!
Reinstalling the 10.6.5 Combo Update helped.
-Download the correct Combo Update (same version (server/normal), same build)
-Stop the Services (like Web and so on..)
-Install the Update
-Restart
-Start Services
-All should work again

Thanks to all of you guys for their help.

Answer (score 0):

I appears that your mysql server is not running. You should debug that portion of your system before looking at your rails app.

A few things to checK:

- Can you connect from the command line?
- Are there startup errors in your mysql log file?
- Did you change IP addresses, share names or anything else that might have stuffed your mysql install?

Comment: Hey Joshua, i cant connect via command line, when i enter the password i get the Error with the Socket. I did not change anything on the System, just the 10.6.5 Update.  Here the mysql log, i hope it is the correct one (just the newest stuff) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/92469/log.rtf      Big thanks!

Comment: [ERROR] Error message file '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys' had only 480 error messages,
but it should contain at least 481 error messages.
Check that the above file is the right Version.     out of mysqlservice.log